# Row normalization before correlation analysis for abundance data

Tags: correlation, normalization, ecology, correspondence-analysis

I work with datasets in which protein abundances are reported across samples.  I have some measurements of biological samples that should be more or less equal in protein abundance.

After getting the data as intensities, they are normalized by subtracting the log$_2$ median of each sample. If I plot these normalized and log transformed intensities, I get a Pearson correlation of around 0.98. But when I divide each row by the row median and log$_2$ transform of the ratio, I get a Pearson correlation of about 0.3. I need to process my data by row normalizing them.

So I am clearly doing something very wrong when performing the correlation analysis after row normalization. How do I perform a correlation analysis on these values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me you're wandering towards correspondence analysis, which is based on modeling row normalized (and column normalized) measures in a low dimensional space.  That literature should provide some principled normalization strategies.
Greenacre has a very readable book on the topic:

Greenacre, Michael. *Correspondence Analysis in Practice*. Chapman and Hall/CRC, 2007.

There is also a related sub-literature on 'log-ratio' analysis that might be helpful.

For explicitly correlational questions, an algebraically identical (so far as I can see) strategy is called canonical correlation analysis.  It's described in Section 9.6 of

Agresti, Alan. *Categorical Data Analysis*. 2nd ed. New York: Wiley-Interscience, 2002.